# ASP.NET MVC save button loading but not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have implemented a save button in my .NET application on the index page. When I click it, it loads, but does not save anything. I am just using the index page for checkboxes. If I uncheck something and save it, it saves, but also unchecks everything else in that row. Nothing happens when I try to check something. Here is the code I'm using:

Index.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("save", "drnos"))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

An example of one of my check box fields:

```
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Soft)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.Soft)
</td>
```

drnosController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult save(Doctor doc)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Save Called");
    db.Entry(doc).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");  
}
```

Here is the whole HTML file:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<drnosv6.Models.Doctor>
@using PagedList.Mvc;

<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Doctors</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) //insert the search bar
{
    <p>
        Find by First Name, Last Name, or RVH ID: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")

        <input type="submit" value="Search" />

    </p>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("save", "drnos"))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('tr:even').addClass('alt-row-class');
    });

</script>

<p>    
</p>

<p>Click on a column header to sort by that column</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("RVH ID", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.IDSortParm })
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Last Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.LastSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("First Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.FirstSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            Middle Initial
        </th>
        <th>
            Degree
        </th>
        <th>
            Group
        </th>
        <th>
            Adm Priv
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("QCPR", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.QCPRSortParm })

        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Keane", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.KeaneSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Orsos", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.OrsosSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Soft", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.SoftSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("3M", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.threeMSortParm })
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    { 
        using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Doctor", FormMethod.Post))

    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RVH_ID_)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Last_Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.First_Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Middle_Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Degree1)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Group)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdmPriv)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QCPR)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Keane)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.Keane)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Orsos)
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.Orsos)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Soft)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.Soft)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.C3M)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.RVH_ID_ })
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.RVH_ID_ })

            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    }

</table>

<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</p>
<br />
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

Comment: `When I click it, it loads`  What do you mean, that the `Edit` action is called?  If it does can you verify that `SaveChanges` is called with a breakpoint?  `If I uncheck something` What are you talking about?  I don't see any checkboxes in your form.  If elements are relevant to the question, then include them as well.

Comment: Your input fields need to be inside your form or they won't POST.

Comment: @Dimi Here is the HTML file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4xs94u7uwahmwut/Index.cshtml?dl=0

Comment: Do I have be registerd under Dropbox  to see your HTML? :)

Comment: @Dimi I don't think so!

Comment: Show the relevant code in your question including the model. It would appear `@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Soft)` is inside a loop and that you have a collection of some objects with a property `Soft`  in typeof `Doctor`. Your usage does not bind to a collection so whatever it is will not be populated on postback.

Answer (score 2):

Your BeginForm or ActionLink has to point to ActionResult Edit.

Comment: Oops, thank you for pointing that out. I had pasted the wrong save function. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

When a form is submitted, only the inputs declared within that form get submitted. You only have the submit button in your form, so there are no other fields to fill out your `Doctor` structure. You need to have your save button on the same form as all your other fields.